# C# WinForms — Как правильно парсить json?

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api

Пишу программу с VK Api, делал GET запрос, далее возникли проблемы с парсингом json. Когда запускаю программу ничего не отображается... Вот код:

```
public class Account
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string bdate { get; set; }
    }

private void Example_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&v=5.64"))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            Account m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(text);

            textBox1.Text = m.id;
            textBox1.Text += " ";
            textBox1.Text += m.first_name;
            textBox1.Text += " ";
            textBox1.Text += m.last_name;
            textBox1.Text += " ";
            textBox1.Text += m.bdate;
        }
    }
```

В чём проблема? За ранее огромное спасибо

Comment: Продебажьте значение `text` и `m` после десериалайза.

Comment: Зачем писать велосипеды? Все уже написано до [нас :)](https://github.com/khrabrovart/Citrina)

Answer (score 5):

Ваш запрос возвращает следующий JSON:

```
{"response":[{"id":210700286,"first_name":"Lindsey","last_name":"Stirling","bdate":"21.9.1986"}]}
```

Он не совпадает с вашим классом `Account`.

Если скопировать его в буфер обмена и выполнить в Visual Studio команду меню Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes, то будут сгенерированы следующие классы:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Response[] response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string bdate { get; set; }
}
```

Становится понятно, что возвращается объект, содержащий *массив* данных о пользователях.

Следующий код должен работать:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(text);

foreach (var response in root.response)
    Console.WriteLine(response.id + " " + response.first_name +
        " " + response.last_name + " " + response.bdate);
```

---

Желательно названия классов и свойств привести к общепринятым в C# стандартам и сделать их более осмысленными:

```
[JsonObject("Rootobject")]
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Account[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject("Response")]
public class Account
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("bdate")]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(text);

foreach (var account in response.Accounts)
    Console.WriteLine(account.Id + " " + account.FirstName +
        " " + account.LastName + " " + account.BirthDate);
```